# jquery trying to add error message

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add an error if a field is blank.

This is my code:

```
if ($('#costproject_costestimates_attributes_1_notes').length) {
  $('#costproject_costestimates_attributes_1_notes').after("<span class='help-inline'>can’t be blank</span>")
}
```

But, my code doesn't work. Getting `assignObj expected` in editor. And `Uncaught Error: ExecJS::ProgramError: Error: Parse error on line 31: Unexpected 'POST_IF'
  (in /Users/davidburton/Sites/ndeavor3/app/assets/javascripts/costprojects.js.coffee)` in browser.

Comment: Can you post a complete code example?

Comment: ^ Because error suggests problem might be somewhere else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following checks that if an element with `#costproject_costestimates_attributes_1_notes` id exists or not:

```
$('#costproject_costestimates_attributes_1_notes').length
```

However, you are checking if this input field has any value or not, so you need `.val()`:

```
if(!$('#costproject_costestimates_attributes_1_notes').val().length)
```

Comment: After changing the first line (add .val()), the problem persists with the second line of code. Even though the second line of code works when it's not part of the `if`.

Comment: can you add `;` at the end of the line just incase? and see the update

Comment: @Reddirt  pay attention to `if(!`